# Remove switch case having different object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to remove switch case block in `GetById` and `Map` methods to improve code readability and clean coding practices in my .NET Core app.

```
public enum IdentityProviderType
{
    Okta = 0,
    Ping = 1,
    Internal = 2
}

public async Task<UserResponseDTO> GetById(string id)
{
    IdentityProviderType provider = //custom logic to retrieve IdentityProviderType enum

    object idpUser = null;
    switch (provider)
    {
        case IdentityProviderType.Okta:
            idpUser = await _oktaUserService.GetById(id);
            break;
        case IdentityProviderType.Ping:
            idpUser = await _pingUserService.GetById(id);
            break;
        case IdentityProviderType.Internal:
            idpUser = await _internalUserService.GetById(id);
            break;
    }
    
    return _mapUserService.Map(idpUser);
}

public class MapUserService
{
    public UserResponseDTO Map(IdentityProviderType provider, object idpUser)
    {
        switch (provider)
        {
            case IdentityProviderType.Okta:
                var oktaUser = (OktaUser)idpUser;
                //Map OktaUser fields to UserResponseDTO fields
                break;
            case IdentityProviderType.Ping:
                var pingUser = (PingUser)idpUser;
                //Map PingUser fields to UserResponseDTO fields
                break;
        case IdentityProviderType.Internal:
                var internalUser = (InternalUser)idpUser;
                //Map InternalUser fields to UserResponseDTO fields
                break;
        }   
    }
}
```

From different resources on the internet regarding the same topic I came to possible idea but not sure how to implement it since I have different objects OktaUser/PingUser/InternalUser.

I started creating something like

```
public abstract class IdpUserService
{
    public abstract object GetById(string id);
}
```

But not sure how to complete it, should I use T or object as output?

Any help how to refactor and get rid of switch case would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code that can help you.

First, you will need to abstract the `IdpUserService` for method `GetById`.

```
public abstract class IdpUserService
{
    public abstract IdpUser GetById(string id);
}
```

And also you will need to abstract the `IdpUser` and move the method `Map` into it.

```
public abstract class IdpUser
{
    public abstract UserResponseDTO Map();
}
```

Now you can implement the specific version of the `IdpUserService`.

```
public class OktaUserService : IdpUserService
{
    public override IdpUser GetById(string id)
    {
        return new OktaUser();
    }
}

public class PingUserService : IdpUserService
{
    public override IdpUser GetById(string id)
    {
        return new PingUser();
    }
}

public class InternalUserService : IdpUserService
{
    public override IdpUser GetById(string id)
    {
        return new InternalUser();
    }
}
```

Similarly, you will need to implement specific versions of `IdpUser` to return from a specific service class.

```
public class OktaUser:IdpUser
{
    public override UserResponseDTO Map()
    {
        return new UserResponseDTO();
    }
}

public class PingUser:IdpUser
{
    public override UserResponseDTO Map()
    {
        return new UserResponseDTO();
    }
}

public class InternalUser:IdpUser
{
    public override UserResponseDTO Map()
    {
        return new UserResponseDTO();
    }
}
```

Now you have multiple implementations of `IdpUserService` from which you want to choose one using the enum `IdentityProviderType`.

We will use dependency injection to construct objects. So we will register all the services to the DI container. And created one class `NamedImpl` to map the service to a specific `IdentityProviderType`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<OktaUserService>();
                services.AddSingleton<PingUserService>();
                services.AddSingleton<InternalUserService>();
                services.AddSingleton<IdpUserServiceFactory>();
                services.AddSingleton<NamedImpl<IdpUserService>>(_ =>
                {
                    return new NamedImpl<IdpUserService>(Test2.IdentityProviderType.Okta.ToString(),
                        _.GetService<OktaUserService>());
                });
                services.AddSingleton<NamedImpl<IdpUserService>>(_ =>
                {
                    return new NamedImpl<IdpUserService>(Test2.IdentityProviderType.Internal.ToString(),
                        _.GetService<InternalUserService>());
                });
                services.AddSingleton<NamedImpl<IdpUserService>>(_ =>
                {
                    return new NamedImpl<IdpUserService>(Test2.IdentityProviderType.Ping.ToString(),
                        _.GetService<PingUserService>());
                });
                services.AddSingleton<Test2>();
            })
            .Build();
        var test2 = host.Services.GetService<Test2>();
        test2.GetById("");
        host.RunAsync().Wait();
    }
```

Now to get specific `IdpUserService` we will create a factory class that get the list of all registered IdpUserService types through the constructor. And a get method which gets the `IdentityProviderType` as a parameter and returns the `IdpUserService` of specific implementation for supplied parameter of `IdentityProviderType`.

```
public class IdpUserServiceFactory
{
    private readonly List<NamedImpl<IdpUserService>> idpUserServices;

    public IdpUserServiceFactory(List<NamedImpl<IdpUserService>> idpUserServices)
    {
        this.idpUserServices = idpUserServices;
    }

    public IdpUserService Get(Test2.IdentityProviderType type)
    {
        return idpUserServices.Where(P => P.Name == type.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()?.Impl;
    }
}
```

Now the code you have posted in question can be structured as bellow to utilize the all changes that we have done above.

```
public class Test2
{
    private readonly IdpUserServiceFactory idpUserServiceFactory;

    public Test2(IdpUserServiceFactory idpUserServiceFactory)
    {
        this.idpUserServiceFactory = idpUserServiceFactory;
    }

    public enum IdentityProviderType
    {
        Okta = 0,
        Ping = 1,
        Internal = 2
    }

    public async Task<UserResponseDTO> GetById(string id)
    {
        IdentityProviderType
            provider = IdentityProviderType.Internal; //custom logic to retrieve IdentityProviderType enum
        IdpUserService idpUserService = this.idpUserServiceFactory.Get(provider);
        IdpUser idpUser = idpUserService.GetById(id);
        return idpUser.Map();
    }
}
```

I know it seems to be over complicated but this way your code would be very extendible as you are using many implementations for the same type of service.

Implementation for `NamedImpl`

```
public class NamedImpl<T>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public T Impl { get; private set; }

    public NamedImpl(string name, T impl)
    {
        Name = name;
        Impl = impl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide implementation of NamedImpl class?

Comment: @lospolloshermanos added in the answer

Comment: Is there an advantage here for using AddSingleton instead of AddTransient/AddScoped?

Comment: @lospolloshermanos that you can use as pe your object lifetime. I just added it to explain, how we can add multiple implementations for the same type and use any specific on the basis of any key.

Comment: Clear. One more question, is creating a interface for IdpUserServiceFactory class acceptable? In order to make code unit testable.

Comment: @lospolloshermanos Generally you will not get cases where you need to abstract the factory. If that is needed then you are looking for the abstract factory pattern. But in the current use case, I see this factory class is responsible for only returning the specific implementation and there is no need to Proxy or Moc the factory implementation for the test cases. So creating an Interface for the factory would be unnecessary here.

Comment: Please take a look at the chat, I've got some issues if you are aware of those

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have only 1 user object with different properties instead of `OktaUser`, `PingUser` and `InternalUser`?

Comment: I dont think it's possible, those are objects defined by those identity providers. OktaUser object contains user information defined by Okta provider, PingUser contains properties defined by Ping identity provider. They might be different, for example OktaUser could contain Groups or some additional data for address that PingUser does not contain.

Comment: But don't have enough info what you want to achieve. What's the difference between these user objects?

Comment: If you have a factory function `GetProvider(IdentityProviderType providerType)` then you can eliminate the switch of the `GetById` and `Map` (but still have one switch/case in `GetProvider`).

(Implementing the `GetById` and `Map` on the returned provider that is declared as an interface.)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to pick the best option without full overview of the codebase. Based on provided code the best option seems to be to abstract `IdpUserService` so it returns `UserResponseDTO` and handle conversions inside the concrete service implementation:

```cs
public abstract class IdpUserService
{
    public abstract UserResponseDTO GetById(string id);
}
```

If there are parts of code which require working with "raw" user then create mapping methods per type (either extension methods or as part of `%SourceName%User` types):

```cs
public async Task<UserResponseDTO> GetById(string id)
{
    IdentityProviderType provider = //custom logic to retrieve IdentityProviderType enum
    UserResponseDTO idpUser = provider switch
    {
        IdentityProviderType.Okta => (await _oktaUserService.GetById(id)).ToUserDto(),
        IdentityProviderType.Ping => (await _pingUserService.GetById(id)).ToUserDto(), 
        ...
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    };
    return idpUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public interface IIdentityProvider {

    Task<UserResponseDTO> GetById(string id);

    UserResponseDTO Map(object idpUser);

}

public static class ProviderFactory {

    public static IIdentityProvider GetIdentityProvider(IdentityProviderType providerType) {
        switch (providerType) {
            case IdentityProviderType.Okta:
                return OktaUserService.Singleton;
            case IdentityProviderType.Ping:
                return PingUserService.Singleton;
            case IdentityProviderType.Internal:
                return InternalUserService.Singleton;
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(IdentityProviderType)} '{providerType}' is not supported!");
    }

}
```